# How can I change to one of the many system installed fonts in KDE5 konsole?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, konsole

I have KDE 5 installed and would like to install a [patched font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) for powerline. I already ran the script to install the fonts into ~/.fonts but when editing the konsole profile, I see a very limited number of fonts, none of which are the ones I installed patch for powerline.

How would I use these fonts in Konsole in KDE5?

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug that the ubuntu system think the patched fonts are not mono. So you cannot see that font in any terminal application's setting, even in gnome-terminal. But as for konsole, we can directly edit the `~/.local/share/konsole/*.profile` file. Here is any example:

```
[Appearance]
ColorScheme=Breeze-VB
Font=DroidSansMono Nerd Font,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

then you can use the font without problem.